# Как приостановить выполнение кода, пока не появится нужный элемент на странице

Tags: javascript

Есть страница с кнопкой "Купить". Если ее нажать, то появляется модальное окно с кнопкой "Подтвердить покупку". Я пытаюсь в консоли запустить скрипт, который поочередно нажмет на эти 2 кнопки.

Вот что пока что получается:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("btn-buy")[0].click(); // клик по кнопке "купить"
document.getElementsByClassName("btn-confirm")[0].click(); // клик по кнопке "подтвердить"
```

Но код не работает т.к. мы после нажатия на кнопку "Купить" сразу же пытаемся нажать на кнопку "Подтвердить", хотя ее еще нет, она пока что равна undefined и появляется чуть-чуть попозже.

Так как же тогда сказать скрипту, чтобы он нажимал на кнопку "Подтвердить" только после того, как она появится?

Comment: @Даниил, ну вернет оно мне false и все, кнопка не кликнется. Мне нужно именно ждать момента когда она появится

Comment: @Farad https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: @Igor, нужно на чистом js.

Answer (score 3):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

> нужно на чистом js

Кхм, кхм.

```
var timer = setInterval(function() {
  var btn = document.querySelector(".btn-confirm");
  if (btn) {
    btn.click();  
    clearInterval(timer);
  }
}, 100);
```

Comment: А MutationObserver теперь не чистый js? :)

Comment: @Zergatul Это как раз то, что я хотел сказать своим "кхм, кхм" :).